# Hera: wingpanel-indicator-session freezes for a long time the first time I click on it

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, session

After I login to my elementary Hera install, I'm able to do most tasks normally, including using indicator panels on wingpanel.  **However, as soon as I try to click on the session indicator to logout/reboot, wingpanel freezes.**

Everything else works fine, but I can't use wingpanel at all (searching for applications, using other applets - nothing works).

**After several minutes, wingpanel is responsive again, and this time, the session indicator is also usable.  This is good till the next time I login.**

This is what I see in **/var/log/syslog** around the time I try to use the session indicator for the first time:

```
Jul 11 23:43:23 elemental PackageKit: daemon start
Jul 11 23:43:23 elemental dbus-daemon[902]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Jul 11 23:43:23 elemental systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Jul 11 23:43:25 elemental io.elementary.a[3271]: ComponentValidator.vala:37: Using .blacklist files is deprecated and will be removed in next version, please use .hiddenapps instead
Jul 11 23:43:26 elemental PackageKit: get-packages transaction /258_eccabcba from uid 1000 finished with success after 962ms
Jul 11 23:43:27 elemental PackageKit: search-name transaction /259_dcecabcb from uid 1000 finished with success after 536ms
Jul 11 23:43:27 elemental PackageKit: get-details transaction /260_ebacebeb from uid 1000 finished with success after 479ms
Jul 11 23:43:28 elemental PackageKit: get-updates transaction /261_acbbaaaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 660ms
Jul 11 23:43:29 elemental systemd-resolved[746]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.86.1.
Jul 11 23:44:30 elemental plank.desktop[2176]: QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Jul 11 23:44:30 elemental plank.desktop[2176]:     Available styles: Windows, Fusion
Jul 11 23:44:30 elemental plank.desktop[2176]: Attribute Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
Jul 11 23:44:31 elemental plank.desktop[2176]: qrc:/QML/DebugMenu.qml:262: TypeError: Cannot call method 'isWasabiEnabled' of undefined
Jul 11 23:44:31 elemental plank.desktop[2176]: qrc:/QML/DebugMenu.qml:289: TypeError: Cannot call method 'isSearchInCommunitiesForceEnabled' of undefined
Jul 11 23:44:31 elemental plank.desktop[2176]: qrc:/QML/DebugMenu.qml:296: TypeError: Cannot call method 'isOOABURISpamCheckerForceEnabled' of undefined
Jul 11 23:44:31 elemental plank.desktop[2176]: qrc:/QML/DebugMenu.qml:304: TypeError: Cannot call method 'isRateCallQualityForceEnabled' of undefined
Jul 11 23:44:42 elemental wingpanel[2174]: session_widgets_userbox_update_state: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Jul 11 23:44:51 elemental wingpanel[2174]: message repeated 2 times: [ session_widgets_userbox_update_state: assertion 'self != NULL' failed]
Jul 11 23:45:22 elemental rtkit-daemon[1337]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jul 11 23:45:59 elemental rtkit-daemon[1337]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.]
```

I'll be happy to provide any more information - I tried uninstalling/re-installing various wingpanel indicators while investigating this, to no avail, before I finally narrowed it down to the session indicator.  Killing wingpanel and manually launching it again didn't help much either.  Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to download the wingpanel from Elementary OS git resource and compile it. If you need a tutorial, let me know. This is probably the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked this question as I was exploring making a switch from Windows 10 to elementary OS as my primary desktop (dual boot).  I have been installing lots of ppas, and just to make sure it wasn't related to one of these,

**I did a clean install,  with all the software I previously installed except for the firejail ppa + firejail, and things have been working without any issue so far**.

Here's why I'm very suspicious that a botched firejail install (blame me for being a newbie) caused the problem:

I had noticed that running `groups` from a terminal after login would show me only my primary group.  Running groups from the console (ctrl-alt-f1) would show me all the groups I belonged to (including docker.. guess how I realized I wasn't in the docker group :) ).  I could also su as my own user from within the terminal, and groups would behave normally.

I suspected firejail at this point, though I had run firecfg --clean prior to removing it (I had problems with dropbox that I wasn't able to solve quickly, and I read some risks about firejail running suid).  However, that was the only explanation I could think of for the weird groups behavior.

As uninstalling/cleaning didn't seem to help, I re-installed the relatively new install and just skipped firejail, and things are working great!

Comment: sudo cat /etc/groups shows all groups in system. id username shows to which groups user belongs. Basic terminal commands will show you what you need. For security use AppArmor. It works without any issue in Elementary OS. I am using it for hardening my system. https://apparmor.net/